# SceneKit: How to arrange buttons in ascending order using for in loop?

Tags: swift, loops, button, label, scenekit

The task is to add 10 buttons (0...9) with labels using for in loop.
I created buttons based on class ButtonPrototype. I assigned label to each button via counter inside for in loop.

It works, but there is incorrect labels order:

[image]

I need another order:

[image]

How can I implement correct order?

Code:

```
func createButtons() {
    
    for y in 0...1 {
        
        for x in 0...4 {
            
            counterForLoop += 1
            
            self.button = ButtonPrototype(pos: .init(  CGFloat(x)/7, CGFloat(y)/7, 0 ), imageName: "\(counterForLoop)")
            
            parentNode.addChildNode(button)
            
            parentNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 100,
                                             y: 100,
                                             z: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just recalculate counterForLoop by adding one and also checking if the value > 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach perfectly makes the trick:

```
for y in 0...1 {

    for x in 0...4 {

        let textNode = SCNNode()
        let ascendingOrder: String = "\(((x+1)+(y*5)) % 10)"
        
        let geo = SCNText(string: ascendingOrder, extrusionDepth: 0.5)
        geo.flatness = 0.04
        geo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: ascendingOrder)
        textNode.geometry = geo

        textNode.position = SCNVector3(x*10, -y*10, 0)
        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
        print(ascendingOrder)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have  at least **two** problems with your code. Your smallest button label is in the lower left and you want it to be in the lower right, and your labels go 0-9, and you want them to go from 1 to 10 (but display 10 as “0”).

To reverse the x ordering, change `X` to 10-x in your creation of a position, and change your imageName to “((counterForLoop+1)%10)”:

```
self.button = ButtonPrototype(
    pos: .init(  
        CGFloat(10-x)/7, 
        CGFloat(y)/7, 
        0), 
    imageName: "\((counterForLoop+1)%10)")
```

By the way, you should add a SceneKit tag to your question. That seems more important than either the `label` tag or the `loops` tag.